# Python adding time to datetime.time object

Tags: python-3.x, python-datetime

I am writing a python script to create a schedule so that we can run some jobs using the schedule object we create. The schedule object has Class variable called schedule, which is list, which contains the allowed schedule for the jobs to run. The parameters for the schedule object is shown below. I need to create a datetime.time object to which I will pass the starttime parameter, example (19,00,00) so that the schedule starts at 19:00:00 and based on the time_increment, the next schedule in the list will be (19,30,00) and so on until the endtime has reached. (example (00,00,00) , once the schedule object has been created, we will link the job with schedule using some method (yet to be created).
My big problem is that I am not able to add the time object. i.e. I created datetime.time object called mystarttime. Then add 30 mins via timedelta and it fails with error below. I don't want to create a datetime.date object as this is time object is not specific to particular date or day. Hence not sure what I am missing and what I need to modify in my code

```
    mystarttime = datetime.time(19,00,00)
    time_to_change = dt.timedelta(minutes=30)
    new_mytime = mytime + time_to_change
```

Error:
My time is 19:00:00
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/suresh/tmp/python-test/test1.py", line 28, in 
main()
File "/Users/suresh/tmp/python-test/test1.py", line 23, in main
new_mytime = mytime + time_to_change
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.timedelta'

My Class definition:

```
class Schedule:
    schedule = []

    def __init__(self, starttime, endtime, time_increment):
        self.starttime = starttime
        self.endtime = endtime
        self.time_increment = time_increment
```

Already specified in the details section.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add/subtract `datetime.time` objects and `datetime.timedelta` objects. if you want `mystarttime` to only contain time information, and be able to add/substract periods of time to it, treat it as another `timedelta` object, representing the duration elapsed since midnight, like so:

```
from datetime import time, timedelta

mystarttime = timedelta(hours = 19, minutes = 00, seconds = 00)
time_to_change = timedelta(minutes=30)
new_mytime = mystarttime + time_to_change

print (f'mystarttime: {mystarttime}')
print (f'time_to_change: {time_to_change}')
print (f'new_mytime: {new_mytime}')

# result:
#     mystarttime: 19:00:00
#     time_to_change: 0:30:00
#     new_mytime: 19:30:00
```